# Proof this set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

How would I start to prove this set is bounded above and below? A hint would be appreciated!

$A:=[0,1)\cup\{2-\frac{1}{n^5}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: Is any element greater than 2?  Is any element less than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in [0,1)$ then $x \ge 0$.  If $x \in \{2-\frac 1{n^5}\}$ then $x \ge 1 > 0$.  (Because $\frac 1{n^5} \le 1$  for all $n$ so if $x= 2 - \frac 1{n^5}$ then $x \ge 2 -1 =1$.).  So if $x$ is in $A$ then $0 \le x$.

So $0$ is a lower bound of $A$.

If $x \in [0,1)$ then $x < 1$.  If $x \in \{2-\frac 1{n^5}\}$ then $x < 2$ (Because $\frac 1{n^5} > 0$ for all $n$ so if $n=2-\frac 1{n^5}$ then $x < 2-0 =2$.).  So if $x \in A$ then either $x < 1 < 2$ or $x < 2$.  So either way, $x < 2$.

So $2$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A set is bounded above and below if and only if there exists an $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|\leq M$ for all $x\in A$.

Now your set is $A=[0,1)\cup\{2-\frac1{n^5}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. What can we say about these two sets? Can you find an $M$ that satisfies each of them?

Comment: True, but don't you think it might be easier for the OP to understand and use the definitions of upper and lower bounds and find the actual upper and lower bounds.  This definition seems too obfuscated for what is a straightforward simple problem.